# Android : HTML in web-view when clicked is opening link in browser

Tags: java, android, html

I am working on an Android project in which I am loading an HTML page from Internet, not locally and then displaying it in WebView. It works fine, but unfortunately, when I click on any of the element
in WebView, it opens the link in Browser.

What changes do I need to make so that any links clicked within the web-view will be opened by Web-view itself. Thank you.

Code :

```
public class ContainerActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contain);

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvPortal);
mWebView.loadUrl("www.domain.com/path/to/index.html");
 WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

        mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
} }
```

contain.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvPortal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. I will accept your answer in 10 minutes, some SO restriction that I can't do both at same time. Thank you. :-)